# Converting UTF8 IAST encoding to SLP in PHP

Tags: php, string

I am trying to write a script which will see whether the string has specific diacritic marks and, convert it to a different transliteration scheme. (Both are transliteration schemes for Sanskrit).

Here is my code.

```
$first = $_POST["first"];
$second = $_POST['second'];
$iast = array("a","A","ā","Ā","i","I","ī","Ī","u","U","ū","Ū","ṛ","Ṛ","ṝ","Ṝ","ḷ","Ḷ","ḹ","Ḹ","e","E","ai","Ai","o","O","au","Au","ṃ","Ṃ","ḥ","Ḥ","k","K","c","C","ṭ","Ṭ","t","T","p","P","kh","Kh","ch","Ch","ṭh","Ṭh","th","Th","ph","Ph","g","G","j","J","ḍ","Ḍ","d","D","b","B","gh","Gh","jh","Jh","ḍh","Ḍh","dh","Dh","bh","Bh","ṅ","Ṅ","ñ","Ñ","ṇ","Ṇ","n","N","m","M","y","Y","r","R","l","L","v","V","ś","Ś","ṣ","Ṣ","s","S","h","H");
$slp  = array("a","a","A","A","i","i","I","I","u","u","U","U","f","f","F","F","x","x","X","X","e","e","E", "E", "o","o","O", "O", "M","M","H","H","k","k","c","c","w","w","t","t","p","p","K", "K", "C", "C", "W", "W", "T", "T", "P", "P", "g","g","j","j","q","q","d","d","b","b","G", "G", "J", "J", "Q", "Q", "D", "D", "B", "B", "N","N","Y","Y","R","R","n","n","m","m","y","Y","r","r","l","l","v","v","S","S","z","z","s","s","h","h");

if (preg_match('/[āĀīĪūŪṛṚṝṜḷḶḹḸṃṂḥḤṭṬḍḌṅṄñÑṇṆśŚṣṢV]/',$first) || preg_match('/[āĀīĪūŪṛṚṝṜḷḶḹḸṃṂḥḤṭṬḍḌṅṄñÑṇṆśŚṣṢV]/',$second))
{
    $first = str_replace($iast,$slp,$first);
    $second = str_replace($iast,$slp,$second);
}
```

I take both the $first and $second from HTML as user input.

Question:
When I enter 
    $first="dhātṛ"; 
and 
    $second = "aṃśaḥ";
The output is "DAtf" + "amsah"..
Desired output is "DAtf" + "aMSaH" as can be seen from the arrays.

I am still not able to see how it identified ṛ and converted it correctly to f ?
And couldn't replace the dots below the m and h -> M and H respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the order of your translation arrays. `str_replace()` uses a dumb algorithm: Replace every found character in the search array with the matching value in the replacement array, starting from the first value in both arrays.

At some point, the "ṃ" gets replaced with an uppercase "M". Later you replace uppercase "M" with lowercase "m". Because `str_replace()` does not remember that this M actually is a replaced "ṃ", it does convert it again.

You can escape from this by rearranging your replacement arrays. If you translate the "easy" letters first, and the diacritic letters later, you might avoid this trap. I successfully tested the correct translation of that "ṃ" by moving the translation of "m" and "M" to the front of the arrays.

On the other hand, you probably do not want to start rearranging values in an array and do all the checks if str_replace() actually works twice on a character. An algorithm must analyze each character only once and translate it into the approriate transliteration. `strtr()` seems to be the PHP function that could do it, but unfortunately it is only usable with single-byte encodings. And there is no `mb_strtr()` function available.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. Could move forward in my coding thanks to you.